# Probability question involving stochastic process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

A stochastic process $\{x_{k}\mid k=1,2,3,...\}$ of zeroes and ones is given with the property that $x_1 = 1, x_2 = 0$ and for every $k>2$ it is true that the probability of the event $x_k = 1$ is equal to $\frac {1}{k-1} \sum_{i=1} ^{k-1} x_i$.

What is the probability of the event $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i=k$ for $1 \le k \le n-1$?

I literally have no idea how to begin this problem. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Maybe I can look at complementary event, but other than that I'm lost.

Comment: What do YOU think?

Comment: I don't know how to do this problem.

Comment: You might think about computing this recursively: You can use the law of total probability to compute $Pr[Sum(t)=m]$ by conditioning on $Sum(t-1)=m$ or $Sum(t-1)=m-1$.

Comment: @Michael The reason: "This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level."

Comment: @Michael "What details and context was missing?" I do not know what you are trying to say exactly, in any case "providing your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it" would do more to advance the cause of a reopening of this question. (Are you Michael=rmercy?)

Comment: @Michael Your last comment, which you posted while I was composing the preceding one, is just (deliberately?) insulting and not worthy of an answer. Sorry.

Comment: Well, was the above hint about recursion on the distribution of the sum of the first $t$ random variables helpful?  Could you work out the details?

Comment: By the way:  I don’t know why that other guy “Did” flagged your question for removal. His comment above just copies a generic message that was already visible on the flag message itself.  Perhaps he thought your question was incomplete (maybe the original posted question was edited), or he just misunderstood your question, or he wanted you to show more work.  His comments above are cryptic.

Comment: I have not tried that yet. I will try that soon.

Comment: I think I figured out the pattern. I got 1/(n-1). I just need to justify it.

Comment: That is what I get, too.  I gave you a thumbs up.